# Pandas increment time series by one minute

Tags: datetime, pandas, time-series

My data is [here](http://www.filedropper.com/test_54).

I want to add a minute to values in STA_STD to get a 5-minute regular time series, if the value in that column contains "23:59:00". Adding one minute should also change to date to next day 00:00 hours.

My code is here

```
 dat=pd.read_csv("temp.csv")
 if(dat['STA_STD'].str.contains("23:59:00")):
     dat['STA_STD_NEW']= pd.to_datetime(dat[dat['STA_STD'].str.contains("23:59:00")]         ['STA_STD'])+datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
 else:
     dat['STA_STD_NEW'] = dat['STA_STD']
```

And this gives me below error:

```
 ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Pandas documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/gotchas.html) talks about the same error.

What is the procedure to iterate through all rows and increment value by one minute, if value contains "23:59:00"?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- You can't use if/else like that to evaluate multiple values at the same time (you would need to iterate over the values, and then do the if/else for each value separately). But using boolean indexing is much better in this case.
- the `str.contains` does not work with datetimes. But you can eg check if the `time` part of the datetime values is equal to `datetime.time(23, 59)`

A small example:

```
In [2]: dat = pd.DataFrame({'STA_STD':pd.date_range('2012-01-01 23:50', periods=10, freq='1min')})

In [3]: dat['STA_STD_NEW'] = dat['STA_STD']

In [4]: dat.loc[dat['STA_STD'].dt.time == datetime.time(23,59), 'STA_STD_NEW'] += datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

In [5]: dat
Out[5]:
              STA_STD         STA_STD_NEW
0 2012-01-01 23:50:00 2012-01-01 23:50:00
1 2012-01-01 23:51:00 2012-01-01 23:51:00
2 2012-01-01 23:52:00 2012-01-01 23:52:00
3 2012-01-01 23:53:00 2012-01-01 23:53:00
4 2012-01-01 23:54:00 2012-01-01 23:54:00
5 2012-01-01 23:55:00 2012-01-01 23:55:00
6 2012-01-01 23:56:00 2012-01-01 23:56:00
7 2012-01-01 23:57:00 2012-01-01 23:57:00
8 2012-01-01 23:58:00 2012-01-01 23:58:00
9 2012-01-01 23:59:00 2012-01-02 00:00:00    <-- increment of 1 minute
```

Using the `dt.time` approach needs pandas >= 0.15

Comment: @Jeff, Can you explain your approach with sample code

Comment: @Chandra @Jeff means that you can replace the `datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)` by `pd.Timedelta('1 minute')`